# Flask app is not start over twisted 16.4.X as wsgi

Tags: python, flask, twisted, wsgi

I have simple Flask app test.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return 'Hello world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Run over twisted 16.3.0 work fine:

```
twistd -n web --port 5000 --wsgi test.app
```

After upgrade twisted to 16.4.0 i have got error on start:

```
No such WSGI application: 'test.app'
```

What is mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are likely picking up the `test` module which is part of the Python standard library. Rename your code file (module) to something else. You also may need to set `PYTHONPATH` so it looks in the directory where code module is.

Comment: Renaming the module does not have effect.
But setting variable PYTHONPATH solves the problem.
Thank you!

Comment: @Vladimir can u share example. where did u used PYTHONPATH ?

Comment: ``PYTHONPATH`` is an environment variable. In this case it would be better to rename the package/module and not use ``test`` name as using a name which mirrors a package in standard library is always a bad idea.

Comment: And what do you get if run run ``python -c 'from my_test import app'``?

Comment: @gB08 example (for module my_test):
Before setting PYNHONPATH:

`$ twistd -n web --port 5000 --wsgi my_test.app`
`twistd: No such WSGI application: 'my_test.app'`


After:

`$ PYTHONPATH=. twistd -n web --port 5000 --wsgi my_test.app`<br/>
`2017-10-09T08:37:29+0400 [twisted.application.app.AppLogger#info] twistd 16.4.1 starting up.`

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton
$ python -c 'from my_test import app'

It's OK

Comment: The ``twistd`` mustn't look in the current directory by default, which is a bit limiting. That is why ``test`` from standard library was found instead.